# cElementTree.iterparse don't use RAM

Tags: python, xml, mongodb, openstreetmap, sax

I am parsing planet openstreetmap file (plant-latest.osm) and writing it's contents to mongodb:

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse

context = iter(iterparse(open('planet-latest.osm'), events=('start', 'end')))
event, root = context.next()

nodeRec = None

for event, elem in context:
    name = elem.tag
    attrs = elem.attrib

    if 'start' == event:
        if name == 'node':
            nodeRec = {'_id':long(attrs['id']), 'geoPoint': [(float(attrs['lon']), float(attrs['lat'])], 'tags':[]} 
        if name == 'tag' and nodeRec:
            k = attrs['k']
            v = attrs['v']
            if k=='name':
                nodeRec['name'] = v
            elif k=='comment':
                nodeRec['comment'] = v
            else:
                nodeRec['tags'].append({'name':k, 'value':v});

    elif 'end' == event:
        if name == 'node':
            ...#write to mongodb
            nodeRec = None
    elem.clear()
    root.clear()
```

Here is the top of the "top" command:

```
PID   USER      PR   NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
14365 root      20   0   384m  88m  15m R  74.8  0.2 398:18.80 python
1975  mongodb   20   0   378g  12g  11g S  32.2 31.7 164:52.52 mongod
```

Why does python use so few RAM?  Can I increase the performance of parsing by using all the memory?

The amount of RAM is 40 GB, ubuntu, python 2.7, mongodb 2.7.3.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing `'` after `planet-latest.osm`

Comment: If you want speed use lxml, also calling iter on an iterator is redundant.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the xml and what you are trying to get?

Comment: sample:   http://be.gis-lab.info/data/osm_dump/dump/latest/RU-KOS.osm.bz2

I have tried lxml, the speed is the same (lxml 104 seconds, cElementTree  103 seconds).

Comment: Try to clean after every 1000 record.